# window.open() opens a new electron browser window instead of native browser window

Tags: html, angular, electron

My electron desktop app loads an angular app into a browser window. That angular app has a button that should open a new website (lets say google.com as an example). When I use the following code...

```
<button (click)="openNew()">Open a new window</button>

openNew() {
  window.open('www.google.com')
}
```

the app opens a new electron browser window. I want the window to open in a native browser window (chrome, firefox, internet explorer, etc). Can this be possible within an electron app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documentation, you can open links on OS default browser with code below

```
const { shell } = require('electron')
shell.openExternal('https://github.com')
```

Read for further information:

> https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenexternalurl-options

Comment: it is now opening as intended!